# Wordpress nextpage number rewrite to text

Tags: php, wordpress

First hello, I have pages in WordPress where I use the nextpage tag. As you know, nextpage brings the pages in the form of numbers.

Ex:

```
http://localhost/twikers/2/ or http://localhost/twikers/3/ etc ..
```

How can we convert these numbers to text like : `http://localhost/twikers/mounted`?
Thanks for any idea and help :)

Comment: This cannot be achieved without messing with core, which shouldn't be done. You should look towards custom taxonomies or parent pages for such a hierarchy.

Comment: i want only that second and third pages